# Spring MVC javax.ws.rs.client - how to pass to REST controller both : @RequestParam and @RequestBody?

Tags: spring-mvc, jax-rs

I have Spring REST controller

```
  @PostMapping("/complexTrace")
    fun complexTrace(@RequestParam projectId: UUID, @RequestBody filter: RegulationTraceFilter): List<RegulationItemTraceResult> {
```

I need to call it with @RequestParam and @RequestBody  but I don't know how. I know how to pass only a body:

```
 val testResponse = this.resteasyClient.target("http://localhost:$port$relativePath")
            .request().header("Authorization", "Bearer $accessToken").post(Entity.json(requestBody))
```

But how to pass  @RequestParam's value?

Answer (score 1):

The `@RequestParam` means query parameter. For your case , the URL looks like `/complexTrace?projectId=bedb3c38-4420-42ec-8151-549f285e9da8`.

You can use `queryParam()` to configure it :

```
val testResponse = this.resteasyClient.target("http://localhost:$port$relativePath")
        .queryParam("projectId", "bedb3c38-4420-42ec-8151-549f285e9da8")
        .request().header("Authorization", "Bearer $accessToken").post(Entity.json(requestBody))
```

Comment: Could be @RequestParam a type different from String?

Comment: yes according to its javadoc.